# Azure flask deploy If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-devops

When I enter to the domain I got this

:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

This is when I enter to diagnostic:
Distributing your web app across multiple instances
The webapp is currently configured to run on only one instance.
Since you have only one instance you can expect downtime because when the App Service platform is upgraded, the instance on which your web app is running will be upgraded. Therefore, your web app process will be restarted and will experience downtime.

I tried to make autoscaling but still the problem

```
app = Flask(__name__)

I put this
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
and this
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True ,port=8080,use_reloader=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a big applications it's better to work on virtual machine not on ready services